# Noisy metallic looking colourful texture reproduction

Tags: print-design, texture

I had created the below seen texture a year ago (in gimp for sure), but can't remember how I did it. I'd like to expand it in size, but cannot remember at all how I did it (was playing around). Obviously I somewhere used the solid noise and the plasma filter in layers, but don't see where it could be done.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's sometimes hard to recreate happy accidents exactly, but this might get you close

Try the Plasma filter with high turbulence. Set the blending mode to Linear Light, over a black filled background layer. Use a Hue-Saturation adjustment to reduce the saturation a bit, maybe bump up the brightness a little.

[image]